# How to program line following and vex claw bot to autonomously pick up pipe on RobotC?

Tags: robot, robotc

Our teacher gave us an assignment which is supposed to be self-taught via YouTube. I can't find a good tutorial, so can anyone explain to me how one would program a vex claw bot to move straight until it finds a line and begins to follow the line (line is black tape). Then we have a ultrasonic sensor which will detect pipes and cause the claw to pick up the pipes.

[Our claw bot looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyH2e.png)

we have three sensors attached to the front

[3 sensors attached like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro9CQ.png)

if any can help I will be really greatful, our teacher hasn't taught us anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a line following task. The approach should be that you move ahead, then use the IR sensors to detect if there is a black line (tape) detected due to the change in IR intensities and then start tracking that line with a normal line follower algorithm.

This link has a nice list of resources for line following tasks. https://www.intorobotics.com/line-following-robot-tutorials-how-to-build-programming-code-and-resources/